# ps: format (separator and width)

Tags: ps

I'd like to specify the column-separator

```
ps -o "%a|%p"        # separator |
```

**and** the column-width

```
ps -o cmd:50,pid     # width 50 for cmd
```

in **one** command.
Is this possible??

It is not about the column-width but I'd like to have the full length command even if it is not the last column.

Comment: should it cover any number of columns with possibility to set width for a certain column?

Comment: I need the FULL command and the PID. The command should be 1st.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -o command is additive, so just do multiple of those:

```
ps -a -o "cmd:50 " -o "|%p"
CMD                                               |  PID
/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --auto| 4158
```

The problem is that you'll get some whitespace around the PID as its right-justified. You can see the 4158 above has a space after the pipe.

Comment: Is there any way of using TAB as delimiter, rather than the pipe ("|")

Answer (score 4):

> I need the FULL command and the PID. The command should be 1st.

As you need to adjust the output for just 2 columns in predefined order (`cmd` and `pid`) 
here's **`ps`** + **`sed`** *"trick"*:

```
ps -ao "cmd:50,pid" | sed 's/./&|/51'
```

Test output:

```
CMD                                                |  PID
nano jq1 -c                                        | 6041
man ps                                             |13714
pager                                              |13725
ps -ao cmd:50,pid                                  |13950
sed s/./&|/51                                      |13951
python                                             |15345
bash -v                                            |16513
bash +v                                            |16645
top                                                |22426
awk -F| -v cmd=xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//Add/value[%d |31412
sh -c xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//Add/value[1]/@IP" -v  |31413
xmlstarlet ed -L -u //Add/value[1]/@IP -v 1.1.1.1  |31414
```